# Can I copy a map on minecraft windows 10 edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I made my little server on Leet. But now I want to move on, I asked them to give me my map but they won't. I just wanted to know if there is any ways to sniff the memory or if there is a little software to sniff the map.

It's the pe version, no MCPC.

Answer (score 1):

### If you do not have direct access to the files on the server, you can't.

Any method to do so would be considered illegal in most countries (including but not limited to the US) and is therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow.